# Refactoring slightly different ifs sequences

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a class in which there is duplicated code, but slightly different:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  @Autowired
  private OtherService otherService;

  private static final int IN_ERROR_1 = 250;
  private static final int IN_ERROR_2 = 1000;
  private static final int IN_ERROR_3 = 251;
  private static final int IN_ERROR_4 = 252;
  private static final int IN_ERROR_5 = 253;

  public String determineField(String value) {
    ResponseDTO response = otherService.determineField(value);
    if(response.getStatus != Status.OK) {
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_1)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR);
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_2)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR);

      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_3)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR);
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_4)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR);
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_5)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR);
    }
    return response.getField();
  }

  public Coords processValues(String value, String otherValue) {
    Coords coords = new Coords();
    ResponseDTO response = otherService.process(value, otherValue);
    if(response.getStatus != Status.OK) {
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_1)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR);
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_2)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR);

      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_3)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR); // DIFFERENT OUT ERROR TYPE FOR IN_ERROR_3 !
      if(response.getRetCode() == IN_ERROR_4)
        throw new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR);
      // MISSING IN_ERROR_5 CASE !
    } else {
      coords.setCode(response.getCode());
      coords.setName(response.getName());
    }
    return coords;
  }
}
```

So here I am trying to refactor the error handling, which, in this class, is actually bigger (more error codes) and repeated more than once.
In fact, most of the class is error handling.

Here's what I've tried:
I initially thought of refactoring this by putting the error handling in a method and using some map to get the out error type. But that was before I noticed the little differences. Now it looks like I won't be able to refactor the way I wanted.

Is there an other way to refactor this that I've not thought about ?

Answer (score 0):

you can build mappings for each error code, but slightly different.

```
static class Key {

    private final int code;
    private boolean discriminator;

    private Key(int code, boolean discriminator){
        this.code = code;
        this.discriminator = discriminator;
    }

    public static Key fromCode(int code){
        return new Key(code, false);
    }

    public static Key fromCodeAndDiscriminator(int code){
        return new Key(code, true);
    }
  
    // hashCode/equals...

}


  Map<Integer, Exception> map = Map.of(
       Key.fromCode(250),                 new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR),
       Key.fromCode(1000),                new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR),
       Key.fromCode(251),                 new CustomException(OutError.FUNC_ERROR),
       Key.fromCodeAndDiscriminator(251), new CustomException(OutError.TECH_ERROR)
       .....
  )
```

Now you can easily distinguish between them on the caller side. If there are more cases where you need to discriminate (for example one more case where `251` might be mapped to a different case), you would need an `enum` as a discriminator, instead of a `boolean`.